# corner case of parsing a time military time string

Tags: c, string, pointers

usually, most military times are like this

```
12:34:56
```

I already figured an method to extract the Hours,mins and secs into their own strings.

However, there is a corner case that i can't seem to figure out

example:

```
12::
```

after extracting the number and converting to integers, result is 0. That is good.
However, i need two 0's to properly represent the time

```
char *hh = argv[2];
char *mm, *ss;
char *array[3];
char *temp =strchr(argv[2],':');
mm = temp + 1;

/*if(*mm == ':'){

  *mm = "00";
}*/

*temp = '\0';
temp = strchr(mm, ':');
ss = temp+1;
*temp = '\0';
```

if you look at the commented if part, that is my attempt to check if the next pointed value is a semicolon. If it is, all i need to do is it with two 0's.

Any clue how to deal with this?

Comment: First of all, why complicate things? Both my answer to your previous question on the subject and the one from unwind here both say the same thing. Simple, easy and quick. But if you want to go for a more complicated variant, why not use e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) instead, it will do some more of the work for you?

Comment: your method is good, but it defeats the purpose of learning for the assignment. i tried strtok but it will not work for this corner case

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to extract this data as integers, not strings.

Something like:

```
bool parse_hms(int *hours, int *minutes, int *seconds, const char *hms)
{
  *hours = *minutes = *seconds = 0;

  return sscanf(hms, "%d:%d:%d", hours, minutes, seconds) > 0;
}
```

should work. Note that the function assumes that all three pointers are valid. It returns `true` if at least one of the numbers was parsed out. Non-parsed numbers will be set to 0 (which of course is also valid as an element value).